# Java crossword : Is there any way to count the spaces in front and behind the words that are printed?

Tags: java, crossword

[Words](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.zip): test file

I'm setting up a programm for my school but I'm in trouble. Can u help me find a way to print the spaces in front and after the words that are printed?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("crossword generator ver. 1.0");
        File wordlist = new File("words.txt");
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(wordlist);
            String words[] = new String[1000000];
            int lineNr = 0;
            while (s.hasNext() && lineNr < 1000000) {
                words[lineNr] = s.nextLine();
                lineNr++;
            }
            System.out.println("Wordlist succesfully loaded");
            Random r = new Random();
            String solution = words[r.nextInt(lineNr)];
            System.out.println("Solution = " + solution);
            for (int i = 0; i<solution.length(); i++){
                char c = solution.charAt(i);
                String word;
                do{
                    word = words[r.nextInt(lineNr)];                    
                } while(word.indexOf(c) == -1);
                System.out.printf("(%c): %s \n", c ,word);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: can you share the test file you are using?

Comment: @Wisthler just shared it

Comment: @ChrisK25 So you basically want to arrange solution words in the proper crossword?

Comment: @Wisthler yeah that's what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You already have the key ingredient in there: `indexOf()`

Creating the amount of spaces is a bit tricky: Creating an amount that is identical to indexOf does exactly the opposite of what we need. First we have to count the highest indexOf, so that we can create *that* amount of spaces in front of every word *minus* the indexOf in the current word.

And we have to remember the words, because we go through the whole loop twice.

The below solution is somewhat dirty - a better way would be to create a new class for instances of the random words (with their lower case version and indexOf), this could also hold a *List* of valid indexOf places so that you don't always use the very first occurrence of the character.

It's just meant to be a stepping stone on the way. There's still plenty to do, e.g. you could decide to only use lower case words, and then in the final output make the "hot" characters upper case.

This code ignores upper/lower case, so you're not locked into certain random words if your solution word starts with an upper case character. The way this is implemented here is dirty, too.

Loading the list, btw., can be greatly simplified, as shown below. This will also avoid the unnecessarily large word list array (which could otherwise sometimes be too small).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("\ncrossword generator ver. 1.0");

    // Load word list.
    final List<String> wordList;
    try {
        final File wordListFile = new File("words.txt");
        wordList = Files.readAllLines(wordListFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("\nWord list successfully loaded.");


    // Pick solution word.
    final int wordCount = wordList.size();
    final Random rand = new Random();
    final String solution = wordList.get(rand.nextInt(wordCount));
    final String solutionLC = solution.toLowerCase(); // So that we won't depend on upper/lower case.
    final int solutionLen = solution.length();
    System.out.println("\nSolution = " + solution + "\n");


    // Choose words whose characters are in the solution word.
    final String[] chosenWords = new String[solutionLen];
    int highestIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < solutionLen; i++) {
        final char c = solutionLC.charAt(i);
        String word;
        int indexOfChar;
        do {
            word = wordList.get(rand.nextInt(wordCount));
            indexOfChar = word.toLowerCase().indexOf(c);
        } while (indexOfChar < 0);
        chosenWords[i] = word;
        highestIndex = Math.max(highestIndex, indexOfChar);
    }


    // Print crossword excerpt.
    for (int i = 0; i < solutionLen; i++) {
        final char cLC = solutionLC.charAt(i);
        final char c = solution.charAt(i);
        final int indexOfChar = chosenWords[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(cLC);
        System.out.println("(" + c + "): " + createStringOfIdenticalCharacters(highestIndex - indexOfChar,
                                                                               ' ') + chosenWords[i]);
    }

}


public static String createStringOfIdenticalCharacters(final int count,
                                                       final char c) {
    final char[] retPreliminary = new char[count];
    Arrays.fill(retPreliminary, c);
    return new String(retPreliminary);
}
```

Example output:

```
crossword generator ver. 1.0

Word list successfully loaded.

Solution = councilor

(c):            Corcyra
(o):        Harbour
(u):      nonillustrative
(n):           unexiled
(c):       sepulchering
(i):        Torrington
(l):         builtin
(o):           nonnarcissistic
(r): Balsamodendron
```

Comment: that is a possible solution but it is totally different from my program. Our teacher said that it is easy and we have to change just some things. :/ But thank you for ur time!!!